# Values sent over channel are not seen as received

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

The code below starts a few workers. Each worker receives a value via a channel which is added to a map where the key is the worker ID and value is the number received. Finally, when I add all the values received, I should get an expected result (in this case 55 because that is what you get when you add from 1..10). In most cases, I am not seeing the expected output. What am I doing wrong here? I do not want to solve it by adding a sleep. I would like to identify the issue programmatically and fix it.

```
type counter struct {
  value int
  count int
}

var data map[string]counter
var lock sync.Mutex

func adder(wid string, n int) {
  defer lock.Unlock()
  lock.Lock()
  d := data[wid]
  d.count++
  d.value += n
  data[wid] = d

  return
}

func main() {
  fmt.Println(os.Getpid())
  data = make(map[string]counter)
  c := make(chan int)
  for w := 1; w <= 3; w++ {  //starting 3 workers here
    go func(wid string) {
      data[wid] = counter{}
      for {
        v, k := <-c
        if !k {
          continue
        }
        adder(wid, v)
      }
    }(strconv.Itoa(w))  // worker is given an ID 
  }
  time.Sleep(1 * time.Second) // If this is not added, only one goroutine is recorded.
  for i := 1; i <= 10; i++ {
    c <- i
  }
  close(c)
  total := 0
  for i, v := range data {
    fmt.Println(i, v)
    total += v.value
  }
  fmt.Println(total)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code has two significant races:

- The initialization of `data[wid] = counter{}` is not synchronized with other goroutines that may be reading and rewriting `data`.
- The worker goroutines do not signal when they are done modifying `data`, which means your main goroutine may read `data` before they finish writing.

You also have a strange construct:

```
for {
    v, k := <-c
    if !k {
        continue
    }
    adder(wid, v)
}
```

`k` will only be false when the channel `c` is closed, after which the goroutine spins as much as it can.  This would be better written as `for v := range c`.

To fix the reading code in the main goroutine, we'll use the more normal `for ... range c` idiom and add a `sync.WaitGroup`, and have each worker invoke `Done()` on the wait-group.  The main goroutine will then wait for them to finish.  To fix the initialization, we'll lock the map (there are other ways to do this, e.g., to set up the map *before* starting any of the goroutines, or to rely on the fact that empty map slots read as zero, but this one is straightforward).  I also took out the extra debug.  The result is [this code](https://play.golang.org/p/Pvi_d2wFwGc), also available on the Go Playground.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    // "os"
    "strconv"
    "sync"
    // "time"
)

type counter struct {
    value int
    count int
}

var data map[string]counter
var lock sync.Mutex
var wg sync.WaitGroup

func adder(wid string, n int) {
    defer lock.Unlock()
    lock.Lock()
    d := data[wid]
    d.count++
    d.value += n
    data[wid] = d
}

func main() {
    // fmt.Println(os.Getpid())
    data = make(map[string]counter)
    c := make(chan int)
    for w := 1; w <= 3; w++ { //starting 3 workers here
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(wid string) {
            lock.Lock()
            data[wid] = counter{}
            lock.Unlock()
            for v := range c {
                adder(wid, v)
            }
            wg.Done()
        }(strconv.Itoa(w)) // worker is given an ID
    }
    for i := 1; i <= 10; i++ {
        c <- i
    }
    close(c)
    wg.Wait()
    total := 0
    for i, v := range data {
        fmt.Println(i, v)
        total += v.value
    }
    fmt.Println(total)
}
```

(This can be improved easily, e.g., there's no reason for `wg` to be global.)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I like @torek's answer but I wanted to post this answer as it contains a bunch of improvements:

1. Reduce the usage of locks (For such simple tasks, avoid locks. If you benchmark it, you'll notice a good difference because my code uses the lock only `numworkers` times).
2. Improve the naming of variables.
3. Remove usage of global vars (Use of global vars should always be as minimum as possible).

The following code adds a number from `minWork` to `maxWork` using `numWorker` spawned goroutines.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

const (
    bufferSize = 1        // Buffer for numChan
    numworkers = 3        // Number of workers doing addition
    minWork    = 1        // Sum from [minWork] (inclusive)
    maxWork    = 10000000 // Sum upto [maxWork] (inclusive)
)

// worker stats
type worker struct {
    workCount int // Number of times, worker worked
    workDone  int // Amount of work done; numbers added
}

// workerMap holds a map for worker(s)
type workerMap struct {
    mu sync.Mutex     // Guards m for safe, concurrent r/w
    m  map[int]worker // Map to hold worker id to worker mapping
}

func main() {
    var (
        totalWorkDone int                          // Total Work Done
        wm            workerMap                    // WorkerMap
        wg            sync.WaitGroup               // WaitGroup
        numChan       = make(chan int, bufferSize) // Channel for nums
    )
    wm.m = make(map[int]worker, numworkers)
    for wid := 0; wid < numworkers; wid++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(id int) {
            var wk worker
            // Wait for numbers
            for n := range numChan {
                wk.workCount++
                wk.workDone += n
            }
            // Fill worker stats
            wm.mu.Lock()
            wm.m[id] = wk
            wm.mu.Unlock()
            wg.Done()
        }(wid)
    }
    // Send numbers for addition by multiple workers
    for i := minWork; i <= maxWork; i++ {
        numChan <- i
    }
    // Close the channel
    close(numChan)
    // Wait for goroutines to finish
    wg.Wait()

    // Print stats
    for k, v := range wm.m {
        fmt.Printf("WorkerID: %d; Work: %+v\n", k, v)
        totalWorkDone += v.workDone
    }
    // Print total work done by all workers
    fmt.Printf("Work Done: %d\n", totalWorkDone)
}
```